# What is this part and how do I remove it?

Tags: motorcycle, transmission, clutch

I am trying to replace my motorbike clutch friction plates, but cannot remove the basket around the plates ( I think that's what people mean when the say 'basket' - the cover over the plates that keeps them aligned and turns them.

I have  this strange partblocking my removal of the basket:

[image]

It has a cover with a spring that presses on the inside of the side cover when the cluctch housing is closed up:

[image]

It looks like I need a special socket with four splines to remove the nut thingy holding it onto the threaded shaft, but have never come across such a tool, and will attempt hammering it anti-clockwise first, before trying to buy or build such a tool.

What could this thing and it's function be? There is nothing inside it when the top is on, and it's shaft is joined to another protruding from the gearbox by a thin chain.

This is on a 2012 Big Boy DRT-250. I think the 'Big Boy'brand, however, is local, in favour of something more generic. It is a cheap Chinese import but quite a nice little bike for the stipend it costs.

Comment: What type of bike (make/model/year) is this on?

Comment: @Paulster2, sorry, see my edit.

Comment: Looking at the pictures, I take it the top pic is the one with the cover off (which is shown in the bottom pic). Going off this assumption, this part looks to be attached to an intermediate gear which changes the rotation so the final drive matches the rotation of the engine. It looks as though you'll need exactly the tool you described, a socket with four protruding fingers to grab the nut. You'll also need the torque spec on this as well when putting it back together. And by all means **CLEAN THE HECK OUT OF THAT THING BEFORE REASSEMBLY!!** :D

Comment: Found out it's a centrifugal oil filter.

Comment: Wow, would have never guessed, lol. Sounds like you're on it, though.

Comment: Did you ever get this taken care of? If so, how did you end up getting the nut off?

Comment: @Paulster2 I sold the bike before fixing it, and my memory is a but vague memory of great brute force lingers. I think I mauled a tube spanner into fitting into that recess, with four 'gripping sides' and undid the holding nut that way.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the pictures, I take it the top pic is the one with the cover off (which is shown in the bottom pic). Going off this assumption, this part looks to be attached to an intermediate gear which changes the rotation so the final drive matches the rotation of the engine. It looks as though you'll need exactly the tool you described, a socket with four protruding fingers to grab the nut. You'll also need the torque spec on this as well when putting it back together. And by all means **CLEAN THE HECK OUT OF THAT THING BEFORE REASSEMBLY!!**